# Content not in view is not hiding like expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like content not in view (viewport?) to be hidden, except the first `<article>`, until the user scrolls down the page enough (maybe until the top of the next `<article>` container reaches about 200px from the bottom of the viewport).

Each `<article>` get's the `hidden` class using the javascript, and when the user has scrolled down enough the `hidden` class is removed using the javascript.

On "My Site" (link below), it's showing the top 2 `<article>`'s, when it should only show the first one. I think it's the image at the top of the page that is causing the problem, but I don't know why.

**[My Site](http://test.michaeldelle.com/portfolio/)**

HTML (only showing 1 `<article>` block since they are all the same)

```
<div class="main-2">
  <!-- There are multiple <article> blocks similar to this -->
  <article class="post">
    <a href="image.png" rel="fwpopup" title="Image Name" class="image-link" target="_blank">
      <img src="image.png" class="image" alt="Site Name">
    </a>
    <h1 class="h-1">Site Name</h1>
    <div class="entry">
      <ul class="work-features">
        <li>Work 1</li>
        <li>Work 2</li>
        <li>Work 3</li>
        <li>Work 4</li>
        <li>Work 5</li>
        <li>Work 6</li>
      </ul>
      <div class="work-description">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis condimentum, neque sed lobortis blandit, tellus magna efficitur velit, sit amet faucibus mi urna et nulla. Fusce varius orci tortor, vitae.
      </div>
    </div>
    <a href="" class="button-more" target="_blank" title="View Website">View Website</a>
  </article>
</div>
```

CSS

```
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
*,
*:before,
*:after {
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
html {
    font-size: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll
}
html,
body {
    height:100%;
}
body {
    font:normal 12px/1 Optima, Candara, Calibri, Arial, sans-serif;
    text-align:center;
    color:#fff;
}
body:after {
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    background:url(../images/main_background.png) 50% 180px no-repeat;
    opacity:0.20;
    content:'';
    z-index:-1;
}
.hidden{
    visibility: hidden;
}
.main-2 .image-link {
    display:inline-block;
    width:75%;
}
.main-2 .image-link .image {
    width:100%;
}
[class|=h] {
    margin-bottom:42px;
    font-size:30px;
    font-weight:normal;
    line-height:1;
}
.portfoliopage .main-2 {
    text-align: center;
}
.portfoliopage .image-link {
    max-width: 1267px;
}
.portfoliopage .post:not(:last-child) {
    padding-bottom:60px;
}
.portfoliopage .post:not(:first-child) {
    border-top:1px dotted #d0d0d0;
    padding-top:60px;
}
.portfoliopage .entry {
    display:inline-block;
    width:60%;
    text-align: left;
}
.portfoliopage .entry .work-features {
    display:inline-block;
    width: 26%;
    padding-top:5px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.portfoliopage .entry .work-features li {
    font-size: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}
.portfoliopage .entry .work-description {
    display:inline-block;
    width: 70%;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height:1.5;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.portfoliopage .entry .work-description ul {
    list-style: inside disc;
}
.portfoliopage .post .button-more {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 14px 20px;
}
```

JS

```
function isScrolledIntoView(elem) {
  var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();

  var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
  var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();

  return ((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.post').each(function() {
    if (!isScrolledIntoView($(this))) {
      $(this).addClass('hidden');
    }
  });
  $(document).on('scroll', function() {
    $('.post.hidden').each(function() {
      if (isScrolledIntoView($(this))) {
        $(this).removeClass('hidden').css({
          'display': 'none'
        }).fadeIn();
      }
    });
  });
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give your first `article` tag a `height` as high as the image.

Images lag in loading from the rest of the DOM. `document.ready` starts working before your image fully loads and stretches the article and pushes other articles beyond viewport.

At the time of `document.ready` firing, the second and third articles are technically in the viewport.

Giving the article fixed initial height should solve your problem.

Alternatively, instead of `$(document).ready` use `$(window).load`. `window.load` fires after everything is fully loaded (DOM and images). But this might slow down page's overall response speed.

Comment: Great answer! How can I set the height of `<article>` to the height of the image in the CSS file if I don't know the image height? The image is displayed on the page using PHP, it's not hard coded into the CSS file. I added `min-height: 400px` to the `.portfoliopage .image-link` block but that doesn't seem like the correct solution. Another solution could be to use jQuery to get the height of the image.

Comment: Well, you have to assume the height of the image. Do you expect image height to vary dramatically? Can you just assume that all front article images will be around and no more than `height:800px`? Then just set the first article tag to 800px.

Comment: I could but if you make the windows smaller (height less then 800px) then the first `<article>` does not load.

Comment: True, but the way I see it, the first article should be excluded from the showing/hiding scroll function altogether. It doesn't make sense to me to hide the main splash image. Again you can try `window.load` see if it's a better solution for you.

Comment: That's a good point. I just won't apply the `hidden` class to the first post.